# ¿Cómo puedo llevar el control del evento "onFocus" por cada celda en Bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Me refiero a, teniendo este código,

```
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
render() {
var cellEditProp = {
  mode: "click",
  blurToSave: true,
  afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell.bind(this),
  beforeSaveCell: this.onBeforeSaveCell.bind(this)
}
return (
    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.dato} cellEdit={cellEditProp}>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">Name</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price">Price</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
);
```

Al igual que en cellEditProp puedo decidir qué hacer cuando guardo el valor (afterSaveCell), ¿cómo podría llevar el control onFocus de cada celda, para comprobar la fila en la que estoy editando por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#beforeSaveCell) sale que `beforeSaveCell` permite tres parámetros, siendo el primero la fila, el segundo el nombre de la celda y tercero el valor de la celda:

```
beforeSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue) {
  // if you dont want to save this editing, just return false to cancel it.
}

render() {
  const cellEdit = {
    mode: 'click', // click cell to edit
    beforeSaveCell: this.beforeSaveCell,
  };
  return(
    <BootstrapTable
      data={ data }
      cellEdit={ cellEdit }>
     //...
    </BootstrapTable>
  );
}
```

No he usado la librería, pero supongo que ese primer parámetro ingresado a  `beforeSaveCell` puede servir a tus necesidades.